# Error message on shuting down Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

i did a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04, only installed couple of programs through apt install and didn't do any major changes to it. When i'm shuting down my laptop i get the following message:

```
failed to send stream file descriptor to service manager: connection refused
```

Why am i getting this message? Should i attempt to fix this, and if so how? I'm not sure what else should i provide so tell me and i'll do it.